# Change of basis

Tags: homework-and-exercises, metric-tensor, vectors, coordinate-systems

If I have a this metric
$$ds^{2}=-dt^2+a^{2}(t)(dx^{2}+dy^{2}+dz^{2})$$

and a vector field $v_{\mu}$, and in this coordinates his components are given by 
$v_{0}=a_{0}$, $v_{1}=a_{1}$,$v_{2}=a_{2}$,$v_{3}=a_{3}$ with $a_{0},a_{1},a_{2},a_{3}$ constants.

If I change to another coordinate system
$$ds^{2}=-dt^2+a^{2}(t)(dr^{2}+r^{2}(d\theta^{2}+sin^{2}\theta d\phi^{2}))$$
What happens to the components of the vector field in this metric?

Comment: A very similar question arises (and does so more simply) in Euclidean space rather than Friedmann spacetime: What happens to a Cartesian vector in spherical polar coordinates?

Comment: Thank you @G.Smith

Comment: Where's the base point of the vector?

Comment: I'm sorry is a vector field. I edited the question.

Comment: What does the metric have to do with this?

Comment: I understand that the components of a vector field, [change](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70493/how-do-i-convert-a-vector-field-in-cartesian-coordinates-to-spherical-coordinate) when you change of coordinates,

Comment: It's $3$ vector - not a $4$ vector. Coordinate changes don't change the metric - you're changing the fiber of the metric. It's the Robertson-Walker line element - a direct product of a base space, $\partial_t$, and the fiber $R^3$ ($k=0$.) Vectors tangent to the base space are horizontal - vectors tangent to the fiber are vertical. Even if you succeed in avoiding the singularity transforming to spherically coordinates or $R^3-0$ ($k=1$), it's unlikely you'll be able to arbitrarily pick a vector in $R^3$ $(k=0)$ and have it land in the proper tangent space on $R^3-0$ ($k=1$).

Comment: And just to be clear, there's nothing wrong with the change of coordinate indicated by G.Smith  - it's what you're trying to do after the coordinate change of the metric that is the problem. As knzhou already pointed out, you need a base point - you can't expect the tangent vector to magical show up at the correct point. In other words, you need a tangent plane base point ($t$,p) and a $v$ on the original manifold then transform them to the new manifold. And by $v$ I mean $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$

Answer (score 6):

The two metrics that you wrote describe the same space-time, this is really just a change of coordinates. Under the transformation $x^\mu \to \tilde{x}^\mu$, a vector transforms as $$v^\mu \to \frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial \tilde{x}^\nu} v^\nu.$$

Answer (score 6):

You need more information.  Knowing how the components of the metric tensor transform for a specific chart transition does not uniquely specify how the coordinates themselves transform.

Specific to your example, which axis $(x,y,$ or $z)$ did you choose for your polar axis?  Where did you choose $\phi=0$?  Did you choose $\phi$ to run conventionally (in the sense that $\hat \theta \times \hat \phi = \hat r$) or the other way?

More explicitly, the coordinate transformations

$$r(x,y,z)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$
$$\theta(x,y,z)=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\right)$$
$$\phi(x,y,z)=\tan^{-1}(x,y)$$

Would cause the metric components to transform the way you suggest, but so would the transformation

$$r(x,y,z)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$
$$\theta(x,y,z)=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\right)$$
$$\phi(x,y,z)=\tan^{-1}(y,z)$$

in which the polar axis was chosen to be along the positive $x$ axis, or

$$r(x,y,z)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$
$$\theta(x,y,z)=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\right)$$
$$\phi(x,y,z)=-\tan^{-1}(x,y)$$

in which $\phi$ was chosen to run "backwards."